# Recycler view mixing up the contents of its items

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

I'm using a recycler view to load a list of posts made by and organization. I've used firestore as the backend.
For loading the image I'm first getting the download Url from storage reference and then using Glide to load image in to the image view.
The issue i'm facing is that since a call to the storage reference is an asynchronous one, by the time it gets the download uri from the server the position of the adapter in OnBindviewHolder is already changed Therefore image gets mixed up.

I've provided the OnBindViewHolder code and the method where i get the download url

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final studentFavouriteUniversityPosts.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(postsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getImageUrl()!=null && 
    !postsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getImageUrl().isEmpty()){

            holder.setPostImage(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }







    }
```

```
public void setPostImage(int position) {

                postImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                placeholder.placeholder(R.color.white);
                //Getting the download uri from the Fire store storage and displaying it using glide.
                storageReference.child(postsList.get(position).getImageUrl())
                        .getDownloadUrl()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                               // Log.d("URI",uri.toString());
                                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholder).load(uri).into(postImage);

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d("ERROR","err loading image file");
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Can anyone of you help me out on this?

EDIT

I changed the structure a bit. So instead of running the storage reference task in adapter, i'm storing the dowload url in the object. Thus the setPostImage method only has the Glide part.

So the method looks like this

```
public void setPostImage(String downloadURL) {
            postImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholder).load(downloadURL).into(postImage);
        }
```

Still i'm getting this issue. I dont know how to resolve it

Comment: This is not a good idea to get the URL from the storage reference while infalting the view. You can rather pass the possible list of item URLs to the adapter itself. This way it will be quick to get the image url which you can pass to Glide to load.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @DurgaM i did that. I stored the urls pas the list to the adapter but I'm still that error.

Comment: @AlexMamo The contents of the recycler view gets mixed up.

Comment: Ok, but what is the question?

Comment: @AlexMamo So how to remove that issue

Answer (score 0):

```
First get the list of urls from firestore from the activity or fragment where you are 
 setting the adapter

1.   public void getImages() { storageReference.child("the child name")
                        .getDownloadUrl()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                               // Log.d("URI",uri.toString());
                               adapter.imagesRetrieved(); 
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d("ERROR","err loading image file");
                            }
                        });
```

}

```
2. Then inside on success listener pass the group of values to the adapter method from the success listener and define the method inside the adapter
  public void imagesRetreived() {
   notifyDataChanged(images);
  }

  private void notifyDataChanged(Images images) {
     this.images = images;
     notifydatasetchanged();  //this one is recycler view inbuilt method 
  }
```